# $100(1.2)^t=\alpha t$. How do I solve for t?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, logarithms

I'm playing with a population model, and I wondered how to find the $t$ when the population goes to zero, with regard to $\alpha$.  I've ended up with this, and I don't know how to solve for t.

Can anyone help?

Comment: This equation cannot be exactly solved, I am afraid, only with numerical methods

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), which satisfies

$$z = W(z) e^{W(z)}$$

In particular, you can rewrite the equation as

$$t e^{-t \ln{1.2}} = \frac{100}{\alpha}$$

or

$$\frac{-100 \ln{1.2}}{\alpha} = (-t\ln{1.2}) e^{-t \ln{1.2}}$$

So $W(\frac{-100 \ln{1.2}}{\alpha}) = -t\ln{1.2}$ and

$$t = \frac{-1}{\ln{1.2}} W\left(\frac{-100 \ln{1.2}}{\alpha}\right)$$

Comment: Yeah I need to learn about that function: it's always popping up in WolframAlpha's explanations.

Comment: Curiousity, does this method give an exact solution?

Comment: I don't understand why can't just log both sides, bring the t down and solve for it. i am getting t=ln(100)/(alpha-ln(1.2))

Comment: @imranfat As far as I know, the W function can (generally) only be evaluated numerically, aside from special points.

Comment: This isn't correct, since you're missing an $\ln{t}$. Taking a log on both sides would give $$\ln{100} + t \ln{1.2} = \ln{\alpha} + \ln{t}$$

Comment: Oh right. Forgot about that. I guess you do need the lambert function

Comment: @T Bongers. Aha, I thought so...